# Can we integrate exactly this problem.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{\cos x}{2x}dx$$  when $\cos x$ is a finite differential family and $x^{-1}$ is a infinite differential family then how we can solve this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2955562/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: WolframAlpha [does not give answer in elementary functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(cos+x)%2F(2x)+dx).

Answer (score 0):

Like $\frac{\sin x}{x},$ this has no elementary antiderivative.  The definite integral can be evaluated by using numerical methods, and the integral from 0 to $\infty$ has nice solution.

You can also evaluate the integral as a Taylor series. Use the fact that $\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$